# Can I get a Canadian Student permit (visa) during covid-19?

Tags: visa, canada, student-visa, covid-19

I am a Yemeni citizen who applied for university in Canada of the spring term and got accepted and then I applied for the Canadian work permit or visa on 7th of March 2020 , and then they requested from me to do biometrics and I did on 10th of March 2020.

Now in my online application it says that visa still under process and it been 2 months since I applied.

I have delayed my studies to the summer term and still waiting for my visa application.

Does the Covid-19 effect my visa processing time ? Will I still get my visa ?

and is Student permit and visa the same thing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the information here https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/coronavirus-covid19/visitors-foreign-workers-students.html#restrictions-students?

Comment: @Traveller , Yes I have checked but I don't know if I fit in that category or not. It says "who has a valid study permit, or were approved for a study permit" , I got approval in university  and applied for visa before March 18. is acceptance latter same as "approved for a study permit". can you please explain